# Subquery con valor máximo si se cumple condición

Tags: mysql, sql

un saludo.
Necesito crear una subquery que retorne la fila con la mayor fecha y que cumpla una condición.

Tengo la siguiente tabla de Clientes:

```
| id_c | cliente  |
|------|----------|
|   1  | Juan     |
|   2  | Luis     |
|   3  | Maria    |
```

Y la siguiente tabla de Ventas:

```
| id_v | venta  | cli_id  | estado    |
|------|--------|---------|-----------|
|   1  | 500    |  2      | cancelado |
|   2  | 100    |  1      | activo    |
|   3  | 150    |  3      | activo    |
|   4  | 200    |  3      | activo    |
|   5  | 500    |  3      | cancelado |
```

La respuesta que espero es:

```
| id_c | cliente  | venta |
|------|----------|-------|
|   1  | juan     | 100   |
|   3  | Maria    | 200   |
```

El valor de la mayor venta de cada socio, sin mostrar los que no están activos.

Estuve probando con una subquery, pero me da errores a pesar de haber probado varias opciones.

```
SELECT c.id_c, c.cliente 
FROM clientes c 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE estado LIKE 'activo' GROUP BY cli_id 
) AS v ON (v.cli_id = c.id_c)
```

El error que me da es que tengo que agregar todos los campos en el GROUP BY, para poderlos referenciar, pero si lo hago, ya no me saldría un cliente único con la venta máxima, sino me salen varios en la subquery.

Ya sé que es un tema que seguro se resuelve rápido, pero llevo desde ayer rompiéndome la cabeza y no encuentro la solución.
Saludos y gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

No veo necesidad directa de la subconsulta, ya con el `JOIN` llevas bien encaminada la query solo bastaría obtener con una función de agregación la máxima venta y con ayuda del `where` como ya lo tienes declarado establecer un filtro.

Entonces la consulta funcional sería así:

```
SELECT cliente.id_c,
       MAX(venta) AS Venta,
       cliente.cliente
FROM cliente
JOIN venta
ON cliente.id_c = venta.cli_id
WHERE venta.estado = "activo"
GROUP BY cliente.id_c, cliente.cliente;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. El ejemplo que puse es una simplificación de lo que necesito, quizás me falto aclarar que necesito consultar varias columnas de ese registro que tenga las mayores ventas, ejemplo, el valor de la venta, la fecha y el tipo de pago. Entonces no sé si al usar el MAX la referencia que haga a las otras columnas traerían los valores correctos.

Comment: Podemos continuar avanzando si llevas la query a la ejecución y nos compartes que resultado obtienes

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu sugerencia, pero si utilizo MAX debo agregar un GROUP BY a todas columnas que estoy mostrando en el SELECT y entonces mostraría más de un cliente, y no un solo cliente como yo necesito. Saludos!

Comment: Recibo el error: cliente.id_c is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.... y así con cada campo en el SELECT

Comment: Con mi propuesta?

Comment: Esta es la query que estoy usando, ya con nombre de campos reales, lo que necesito es seleccionar el Socio y entre sus Planes seleccionar los datos del que tenga la mayor fecha

Comment: SELECT s.SocioID, CONCAT(s.Nombre, ' ', s.Apellidos) AS Nombre, s.FechaVencimiento, MAX(h.FechaFinal) AS FechaFinal  
FROM Socio s 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[HistorialPlanes] h ON (h.SocioID = s.SocioID) 
WHERE s.SocioID = 28 
GROUP BY s.SocioID, s.Nombre, s.Apellidos, s.FechaVencimiento, h.FechaFinal

Comment: Al necesitar agregar la FechaFInal en el GROUP BY ya me salen Socios repetidos